# Toggle visibility upon posting to iframe

Tags: jquery, post, iframe, toggle, visibility

I'm trying to toggle the visibility of an iframe when it has form data posted to it. I know it's an unsafe operation because the iframe content is hosted elsewhere, please disregard that for the sake of this question... I already have the form data posting to the iframe successfully, now I need it to toggle display when it posts.

Here's what I have so far, I'm pretty new to js so apologies if the syntax is completely wrong...

```
$.post('http://idx.mlspin.com/search.asp?aid=NB900549', function(data) {
    $('#MLSSearchForm').serialize();
    $('#MLSframe').html(data);
    posting.done(function( data ) {
    $('#MLSframe').css('display','block');
    $('#main_container').css('display','none');
  });
}, 'html');
```

Here's a link to the live test page, note that the form to post is the "sales" tab in the sidebar, not "rentals":

http://mraboston.com/wp-content/themes/whiteboard/test_page.html

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on that request?

Comment: its posting form data... and I am getting that response but it successfully posts and returns the results in the iframe